# MVC Entites exception, really weird

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im saving some locations/cities in my database.

My locations/cities DOES get saved althrough my  `this._entities.SaveChanges();` throws an execption that goes something like:

`The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while       updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner     exception message:AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.`

I dont really know whats the problem since it worked before and this changes should not affect it really...

Here's some code:
First off i get all the objects into currentLocation.
I loop them through a foreach to add item to method Add().
Last i call for _entites.SaveChanges(). Everything gets saved but i get an error...

```
           var webService = new WeatherWebService();
            currentLocation = webService.FindLocation(city);

            // ...save the user in the database.
            foreach (var item in currentLocation)
            {
                this._repository.Add(item);
            }

            this._repository.Save();

    public override void Add(Location location)
    {
        this._entities.Locations.AddObject(location);
    }

    public override void Save()
    {
        this._entities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Seems if the result i only one city it gets saved but if its multiple it saves and throws exception above...!?

Comment: _Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges_ (i.e. before `SaveChanges`) did you check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem sloved, seems you have to output a id from the Auto Increment... else it will make each post id 0 and therefor it thinks its several with same ID.

Used something like NewId as @@SCOPE_IDENTIY